# NPM build confusion

Tags: javascript, npm, build

I am new to working with NPM/Webpack build flow for frontend development. I've read through some tutorials and have helped some, but I have a few questions if someone can help explain them better.

When I start a new project, I think of it a singular component to my bigger project (website in this case). When I setup npm within my project folder it installs 80MB of packages. When I build my little hello, world example - I get a 172KB dist.js file.

Seems like everything is getting packed in there.

So my question is how to not include the kitchen sink and just my requirements for this project?

And also, if I build a similar project with the same requirements, how do I make sure I don't have 2 of the same libraries loaded within a webpage for example, I would want 'lodash' loaded only once.

Thanks
Rich

Comment: How do you setup npm? Where are those packages coming from?

Comment: All the tutorials I've done, use `npm install` command, so from npm repositories.

Comment: I wanted to ask, what package do you install? Do you need them? You could start out with `npm init` and have no dependecy and later add the needed packages.

Comment: It's possible I am not 100% sure what dependencies are included here. But within my package.json file, I have:
`
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
`

Comment: I should add, there are a ton more in devDependencies.

Comment: How did they get there? I just try to understand how you bootstrap your project. How do you do that? What does `When I setup npm...` mean? Which steps are you performing?

Comment: `npm install -g vue-cli`
`vue init webpack my-project`
`cd my-project`
`npm install`
`npm run dev` Because of errors and other things, I know I installed other things as well. webpack-server and other packages like `lodash` and `request`.